# Will I get denied access to Israel?

Tags: visas, international-travel, borders, israel

I am Italian-Jordanian (my parents are Jordanian, I have dual citizenship) and I was born, raised and live in Italy. I am planing to travel and I would like to go visit Israel for almost a week.

I am worried I will be denied access at Tel Aviv airport. I contacted the embassy and they say that I will not have problems (as an Italian citizen), but they probably will ask for my Jordanian passport.

What should I do? Should I buy the ticket and go without worries?

Comment: "but they will probably ask for my Jordanian passport" is this what they told you at the embassy, or is this your own assumption? I have friends that travel with dual citizenship and they are never asked for the other passport. As far as I know, passport control has no way of knowing that you are a dual citizen

Comment: I do not see any problems here. Israel does not ban Jordanian citizens from entering its soil. Use your Italian passport and be nice. If they ask for your Jordanian passport, you present one.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I cleaned up your question a bit (we don't like "social niceties" in the question and want to focus on the questions and answers).

Answer (score 5):

Although you are never guaranteed entry to any country, and Israeli border officials do interview you and exercise judgment in deciding whether you will be referred for additional screening or even denied entry entirely, nothing you have reported in your question indicates that you would not be allowed to enter Israel.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official or even apparent problem for you to enter Israel.
Jordanian passport holders can ( and do ) enter Israel without a problem.

The only thing that might happen ( do to other factors like Name / Appearance ) is that you will be held for short questioning ( like I have on multiple occasions for various reasons ) to check other factors underlying your visit ( for example - relatives in Israel / Palestinian territories, reason for entering etc ).

Be sure to give the right and honest answers and don't panic. The young people holding these "interviews" are usually firm but nice and if there is really no other problematic reason or factor - you will be on your way in one minute.

The Jordanian origins or passport by themselves are not a factor.

On a side note - I see many questions in here regarding similar fears of having Arab / Muslim origins travelling to Israel and although I can understand the premise - people tend to forget that there is a large population of Muslims Arabs in Israel that live there, work there, have an Israeli citizenship and passport and the local security / authorities are no strangers to Arab / Muslims - and in fact many of them can even speak the Arab language to some extent.

Comment: There are indeed many Arab citizens of Israel, who travel freely, but they all go through an extra security check every time they fly. The OP should expect the same.

Comment: @ugoren `The OP should expect the same` - isn't that what I wrote ?

Comment: It is, you just didn't write what `the same` is. Arabs go through extra security in TLV, even if they're Israeli citizens.